# what is the recommended web server for images?

Tags: web-server

I have a new server for only images. what is the recommended web server to serve only static content (I have only images) ?

My hardware is:
CPU: intel xeon X3460
RAM: 16G

OS is CentOS5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[nginx](http://nginx.org/) and [lighttpd](http://lighttpd.net/) are often used for this purpose although you could technically use any web server.

In general, the web server you decide to use should be as lightweight as possible and support `sendfile(2)` and the more advanced event handling you OS provides (e. g. `epoll` on Linux, `kqueue` on FreeBSD, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

nginx may be the best choice, as it looks like it does the best job serving static content, very light weight, extremely low mem footprint..!

Answer (score 2):

[ngnix](http://nginx.org/) for sure